# What alternatives to If-Else statements do batch files have?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat file for my shell:startup for ease-of-access. .bat does not accept else as a term. What can I do to make my code work? And if there is no 'else' alternative,is there an operator for not-equivilant?

Code:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Desktop Startup Initiated...
cd "C:\Users\User1\Desktop
goto start


:start
pause
set /p x=Please select an option.     1.Heavy start     2.Light start               Enter Here:

if %x% == 1 (goto heavy)
if %x% == 2 (goto light)
else (echo Invalid.
pause
goto :start)

:light
start Slack.lnk
start Outlook.lnk
exit

:heavy
start chrome.exe
start Review.txt
start Notes.txt
start Slack.lnk
start Outlook.lnk
exit
```

if there is no else alternative, I can make not-equals arguments in its place to redirect to start.

Comment: `else` is perfectly valid, it just needs to be on the same line as the `)` from the `if`

Comment: You don't actually need the `else`. Just let it drop through to the next line. Also, if you put `:light` as the line after `start Notes.txt` you could remove the current `:light` section.

Comment: Open a command prompt window, type `if /?` and read the help text very carefully; you will find the syntax of `if`/`else` blocks and all the available comparison operators in addition to `==`, like `EQU`, `NEQ`, for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CHOICE instead, you can then set a default option with time out. *(this chooses Light after 30 seconds without response)*

```dos
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Desktop Startup Initiated...
PUSHD "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
CHOICE /C LH /T 30 /D L /M "Please select Light or Heavy start "
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :Heavy 
START Slack.lnk
START Outlook.lnk
EXIT/B
:Heavy
START chrome.exe
START Review.txt
START Notes.txt
START Slack.lnk
START Outlook.lnk
```

Answer (score 1):

Why using else ?
Logically if its not equal to 1 or 2 it will go to the invalid statement

```
if %x% == 1 goto heavy
if %x% == 2 goto light
echo Invalid.
pause
goto :start
```

If you really want to use the `else`

```
if %x% == 1 goto heavy
if %x% == 2 (goto light
   ) else (
   echo Invalid.
   pause
   goto :start
   )
```